# I think I've found the antiderivative of $x^x$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

If you do integration by parts for $x^x$, while repeatedly using $dx$ as $dv$ and $x^x$ for $u$, you get an expansion that looks like $$\int x^xdx=xx^x -\int xx^x(1+\ln x)dx$$ Because we can find $x^x$ as many times as we want, we can keep solving the integral with dv as some power of x, we can expand to something like: $$\int x^xdx = xx^x-\frac{x^2}{2} \frac{d}{dx}x^x+\frac{x^3}{6}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dx}x^x-...=\sum^\infty_{n=1}{(-1)^{n+1} \left(\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)\left(\frac{d^{n-1}}{(dx)^{n-1}}\right)}$$ This seems right on paper but I think I've made a mistake somewhere because I've been told everywhere that there is no antiderivative for $x^x$

Comment: An infinite sum is usually not considered to be a closed form antiderivate.

Comment: What does "as many times as we want" mean here? This only works if the error terms converge to $0.$

Comment: Your series is a differential operator, not a function. By the way, there is no _elementary_ antiderivative, but there are antiderivatives, including $\int_0^xt^tdt$.

Comment: No, because the unknown integral appears on RHS.

Comment: Here's an antiderivative for $x^x$: $f(x) = \int_1^x e^{t\ln(t)}\,dt$.... When people say "there is no antiderviative", they mean that there is no function that can be written down in closed form using the "standard" functions (rational functions, exponentials, logarithms, trigonometric functions, inverse trigonometric functions, etc). Infinite series don't count, because they aren't "closed forms".

Comment: @J.G. I would not start that integral at $0$ if I were you...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Since $\lim_{t\to0^+}t^t=1$ while $x^x$ is in this context defined only for $x\ge0$, I'm not sure what your concern is.

Comment: @J.G. That the integral is improper. $x^x = e^{x\ln x}$ is undefined at $0$. No need to have to deal with improper integrals,

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I guess I could write the intended antiderivative as $\int_0^x\lim_{u\to t^+}u^udt$.

Comment: @J.G. Or you could have avoided the whole thing by having the integral go from $1$ to $x$....

Comment: What is the argument of the $\left(\frac{d^{n-1}}{(dx)^{n-1}}\right)$?

Comment: @TymaGaidash I think he meant to type $x^x$ as his argument.